# template.php function for adding field CSS classes

Tags: theming, forms

I'm using Drupal 7 with Bootstrap. I copied the sub-theme and renamed all the files accordingly and everything works fine, however I'm having problems with my sub-theme's `template.php` not doing what it should.

I am trying to add specific CSS classes to my form field while editing the form or adding new content. I tried following http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/adding-css-classes-fields-drupal, but I can't change the field's classses.

This is the code I have in template.php.

```
/**
 * Overrides theme_field()
 * Remove the hard coded classes so we can add them in preprocess functions.
 */

function MojCrm_field($variables) {
  $output = '';

  // Render the label, if it's not hidden.
  if (!$variables['label_hidden']) {
    $output .= '<div ' . $variables['title_attributes'] . '>' . $variables['label'] . ':&nbsp;</div>';
  }

  // Render the items.
  $output .= '<div ' . $variables['content_attributes'] . '>';
  foreach ($variables['items'] as $delta => $item) {
    $output .= '<div ' . $variables['item_attributes'][$delta] . '>' . drupal_render($item) . '</div>';
  }
  $output .= '</div>';

  // Render the top-level DIV.
  $output = '<div class="' . $variables['classes'] . '"' . $variables['attributes'] . '>' . $output . '</div>';

  return $output;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_field()
 */

function MojCrm_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
  /* Set shortcut variables. Hooray for less typing! */
  $name = $vars['element']['#field_name'];
  $bundle = $vars['element']['#bundle'];
  $mode = $vars['element']['#view_mode'];
  $classes = &$vars['classes_array'];
  $title_classes = &$vars['title_attributes_array']['class'];
  $content_classes = &$vars['content_attributes_array']['class'];
  $item_classes = array();

  /* Global field classes */
  $classes[] = 'field-wrapper';
  $title_classes[] = 'field-label';
  $content_classes[] = 'field-items';
  $item_classes[] = 'field-item';


  /* Add specific classes to targeted fields */

  switch ($name) {
    case 'field_baza_direktor':
      $title_classes[] = 'inline';
      $content_classes[] = 'col-sm-6';
      break;
  }

}
```

Comment: Isn't `$variables['classes']` an array?

Answer (score 1):

Using `yourtheme_preprocess_field()` won't work for forms because `theme_field()` isn't called. Instead, [`theme_form_element()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7) is executed, which builds the form element wrapper.
If you want to use/override the input itself override the corresponding theme function, e.g. `theme_textfield()` and so on.

Another way could be using `hook_form_alter()`/`hook_FORMID_form_alter()` if you want to override the attributes for a specific form only.